# The function to fill the ring in the grayscale image the fastest

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I have a picture of a ring type part and I want to measure the outer and inner diameters of this part. I use a library called subpixel-edges to find edge coordinates. However, my problem is that the subpixel-edges library outputs all the dots as a single array. So I can't find which edge information is inner diameter and which is outer diameter. I wrote a function for this. This function returns two images as output. These are a filled-in image with only the outside diameter information remaining, and the other image with the outside filled in, with only the inside diameter image remaining.

Cleaned Image

[image]

Filled Image

[image]

Inner Diameter

[image]

Here I am using "from skiimage.morphology import reconstruction" to fill in.

```
def edge_finder(img):
    img = 255-img
    seed = np.ones_like(img)*255
    img[ : ,0] = 0
    img[ : ,-1] = 0
    img[ 0 ,:] = 0
    img[ -1 ,:] = 0
    seed[ : ,0] = 0
    seed[ : ,-1] = 0
    seed[ 0 ,:] = 0
    seed[ -1 ,:] = 0

    fill = reconstruction(seed, img, method='erosion')     
    cv2.imwrite("outer.bmp", fill)
    cv2.imwrite("inner.bmp", fill-img)  

    return fill, fill-img       # returns outer and inner diameter images
```

That's why the process is moving much slower than I should. Is it possible to do this at much higher speeds? Can you help me with this? Thanks.

(Note: The images I uploaded here are smaller size images. Actually, the process takes more than half a second because the size of the ones I'm dealing with is larger. I couldn't upload them here due to the file size limit.)

Comment: Did you try opencv findContours followed by drawContours? If you only need the diameters you csn use minEnclosingCircle or boundingRect on the contours.

Comment: If the ring is always in the image center you can scan a single row and search for black/white changes

Comment: A mixture could be to search for the outer contour only (maybe resized image with reduced resolution) and then scan the center row of that contour's boundingRect in the full size image.

Comment: Note that if the ring is a circle (i.e. not an ellipse) and the coordinates of 3 points on the circumference are known, you can calculate the center coordinates and the radius of the circle. If the image has only one ring, the coordinates of 3 points on the circumference are relatively easy to find.

Comment: @ken Your approach makes sense. that's how I normally do it, but part sizes and part types can change. Sometimes it can come in ellipse-like parts. So I need a more stable approach.

Comment: @Mika I did not understand what you said

Comment: You can share the correct, full-size images using Dropbox or Google Drive links. Filling/reconstructing doesn't seem likely to be a fast solution. You may do better to post your points instead.

Comment: If the question is about optimization, please provide concrete examples and descriptions as much as possible. In general, the more stable the solution, the slower it will be. Also, I checked about subpixel-edges, it seems to be a pure Python implementation, which usually means quite slow. With OpenCV you can try `cv2.findContours(cleaned_image, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)` to get the outer and inner edges separately. However, I cannot determine if this is as fast as you want it to be. Please try and update your question.

Comment: Isn't it possible to find only the inner circle by filling the outer background with black and then detecting edge?

Comment: yes, you can flood fill from the top left corner to fill the outer white with black, if that is what you want.